# Returning Back to Table View After Exit from Safari Browser

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

How do get back to your table view when you are done with the safari browser so that it wont have to exit the application and anytime you access safari, it will just take you back directly to your last table view not exit the application

Answer (score 1):

Just add a viewcontroller with a UIWebview on it, and a done button on a UIToolbar.  Have the webview load the page you are interested and hitting done removes the view or pops it off the nav stack.